# How to access Activity context in the Service class in android

Tags: android

I have an android app, where i am starting a service from an activity. I want to access the activity context from the service class and not the application context to perform some action. How can i achieve this

Comment: "where i am starting a service from an activity" -- why? "I want to access the activity context from the service class" -- the point behind having a service is to do work when you do *not* have an activity around.

Comment: The problem is that, from Service  class i am inflating a layout and adding it to WindowManager . While inflating the layout, the context being a Service context and not the activity context, i am getting binary xml exception "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)" . What is the way to get around this

Answer (score 0):

> While inflating the layout, the context being a Service context and not the activity context, i am getting binary xml exception "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)" . What is the way to get around this

Eliminate everything from the layout that requires `Theme.AppCompat` and stick to framework widgets. AFAIK Jetpack Compose can also be used here, instead of layout resources, though it requires some additional setup.